# LM60BIZ/NOPB and Temperature sensor not Listed

Tags: gpio

I have tried to use [this](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/freshers/raspberrypi/tutorials/temperature/) guide to help me but when that didn't work I found this [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/ds18b20-temperature-sensor-not-listed/3609#3609) (which gave me a nice visual) but still the Raspberry Pi cannot see my sensors. I have upgraded to the unsupported wheezy and ran this (with same result)

I've then used the console to run;

```
sudo modprobe w1-gpio
sudo modprobe w1-therm
cd /sys/bus/w1/devices/
```

This all works fine. However, when type `ls`, the guide tells me that I should see the serial number of the sensor listed followed by `w1_bus_master1`.

All I actually get is `w1_bus_master1`, but no serial number. I've tried everything I can think of (which isn't much). Is anybody able to offer some guidance on what the problem might be?

I have two sensors: (I think the reason is the type of sensors but ???)

- LM60BIZ/NOPB
- LM19CIZ/NOPB

Both from Mouser.com

I have two Rev. 1 Raspberry Pi and neither board can see these.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The LM60 and LM19 are analog sensors, and the GPIO ports have no analogue inputs. You'll need a [DS18B20](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/245) digital sensor.

Comment: Great, thanks. I picked up a new digital DS18b20 sensor and all is working now.