# DS18B20 not listed in /sys/bus/w1/devices

Tags: gpio, temperature, ds18b20

I'm starting work on a fermentation monitor using the [Adafruit temperature sensing](https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing.pdf) tutorial, a RPi B+ running Raspbian, a 4.7 kOhm resistor and a DS18B20 to which I've soldered male breadboard pins. After wiring exactly as the tutorial states (on multiple breadboards), I do:

```
sudo modprobe w1-gpio
sudo modprobe w1-therm
ls /sys/bus/w1/devices
```

But I only get a folder named "w1_bus_master1"; no 28-xxx folders. I understand this is a common question, so here is what I have done so far:

- This DS18B20 has worked (and still works) when connected to my Arduino, so the sensor is not faulty.
- Tried connecting the sensor to the 5V GPIO with no success.
- Tried wiring the resistor as it is on my Arduino's breadboard, with the power/data/ground on one column, the power/data resistor on the next column, and the sensor pins on the column after that; no luck.
- Tried using the same wiring on multiple breadboards.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

[A picture of the connections.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV3dn.jpg)

Comment: A photo and a precise description of the connections between the Pi and sensor (including the resistor connections) may be useful.

Comment: As far as I can tell the connections seem correct.  Ground - Ground,  3V3 - Power, gpio 4 - data, data pulled up to 3V3 via resistor.

Comment: I've just set one up and it works fine.  The obvious error is swapping the ground and power connections.

Comment: What version are running? In the terminal type `uname -a`

Comment: Related: [DS18b20 temperature sensor not listed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found it!

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

add :

**dtoverlay=w1-gpio**

this has to do with kernel update, find more info in this  [link](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=98407)

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hell yeah! I was really struggling with this! I had a working Pi2 with a 10-probe 1-wire network. I made a new network with a Pi3 and couldn't get it to work even with the sensor cluster from the old Pi2. If I could give you more than +1 I would. Thanks, this worked a charm!