# DS18b20 temperature sensor not found

Tags: sensor, temperature

Trying to install DS18b20 temperature sensor but it looks like the RPi cannot find it.

From console:

```
sudo modprobe w1-gpio
sudo modprobe w1-therm
cd /sys/bus/w1/devices/
ls
```

But there is nothing there :(

Have I done the wiring correct

[image]

Comment: Does http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27073/firmware-3-18-x-breaks-i2c-spi-audio-lirc-1-wire-e-g-dev-i2c-1-no-such-f apply?

Comment: Does http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/ds18b20-temperature-sensor-not-listed apply?

Comment: Does http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26623/ds18b20-not-listed-in-sys-bus-w1-devices apply?

Comment: Check out if the cable colors from the sensor correspond to those which you connected to the board.

Answer (score 4):

Nr 3 did the work. Thx for quick help.

`sudo nano /boot/config.txt
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4`