# LM35 temperature sensor not listed

Tags: sensor

I followed this guide: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/freshers/raspberrypi/tutorials/temperature/ to setup a LM35 temperature sensor on my Raspberry Pi.

Changed the raspi.list file as well to `deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy main untested` and then run apt-get update + apt-get upgrade. All that went without a hitch.
I've then used the console to run:

```
sudo modprobe w1-gpio
sudo modprobe w1-therm
cd /sys/bus/w1/devices/
```

When I type `ls` I see the sensor listed with also `w1_bus_master1`. By entering the folder, though, I can't see `w1_slave`.

I tried to follow the solution posted in  [DS18b20 temperature sensor not listed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/ds18b20-temperature-sensor-not-listed) , but the wiring resulted to be wrong in the picture (or my sensor has inverted poles) and I ended up with a burnt finger. Is there a way to show `w1_slave`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An LM35 is not a 1-wire sensor.  Its output is an analogue voltage proportional to the temperature.

The Pi has no analogue inputs or outputs.  You will need to use an ADC to read the sensor.